# Which version of Android supports HTTPS

Tags: android

I have one WCF web service hosted on https. which android versions supports https. I know that Android 2.2 supports https. Any code for older version??

Comment: What do you mean support? What code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All versions of Android let you make requests to HTTPS servers.

Answer (score 0):

On android you can use java libraries. Since java supports https, android supports it also.